# how to resize dropdown width and add tooltip to display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dropdown and I want to resize its width to 150 px.  I also want to add a tooltip, such that if I have select text length more than 150 px, it is shown using the tooltip.  Can I have an example please. After the selection, I want it to take the width of the selected text.

```
<select id="myDropDownList" >
                <option>Loading...</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Razor engine, then you can make use of the following

```
@Html.DropDownList("yourDropDownId", String.Empty, new { @class = "dropDown"})
```

and in CSS

```
.dropDown { width:150px; }
```

**NOTE:** The yourDropDownId should be a selectlist item in the ViewBag which should be set in the controller action like following

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    ViewBag.yourDropDownId = new SelectList(db.Table1, "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

**UPDATE**

With your existing code , you can assign the class attribute for select tag like following

```
<select id="myDropDownList" title="Please enter 150 characters only" class="dropDown">
    <option>Loading...</option>
</select>
```

And use the same above code for the dropDown.

Comment: the initial size is working fine, i`ts after the selection I want to add a tooltio that will show the entire text of the dropdown selected text

Comment: in that case, you will have to use some javascript onselectionchanged code that changes the title value for select tag.